# Download videos from UNFCCC webcast service (azuremediaplayer - azure.net)

Tags: video-streaming, azure, video-download

We are trying to download the video stream from the UNFCCC webcasts, that is, from the Climate Change Conference.

"[Video DownloadHelper](http://www.downloadhelper.net/)" provides no good solution, as there are 4 audio streams and one video stream and the VDH can not combine these to a useful file, but creates a myriad of files of no direct use. 
[image: Download helper drop down menu]

The video is streaming here:
http://unfccc.cloud.streamworld.de/webcast/cop-cmp-cma-closing-plenaries

Answer (score 1):

This might help you: https://kwizzu.com/construct.html

Either you merge them together: Merging audio and video using ffmpeg

Or you can use VLC to "watch"/"hear" multiple files at the same time:  Watching separate video and audio files

The most advanced solution is to create one video file with multiple audio tracks. This is described here: https://superuser.com/questions/1078298/ffmpeg-combine-multiple-audio-files-and-one-video-in-to-the-multi-language-vid